# Function does not enter the else

Tags: javascript

I am using the following function in a `datatables` table.

```
function novaData(d){
   var dia  = d.getDate().toString();
   dia = (dia.length == 1) ? '0'+dia : dia;
   var mes  = (d.getMonth()+1).toString();
   mes = (mes.length == 1) ? '0'+mes : mes;
   var ano = d.getFullYear();
   return dia+"-"+mes+"-"+ano;
}

  class CellDate{
    constructor( start_date ){
        this.date = start_date;
    }
getNextDate(){
   if($('#user_data tbody tr').length){
      var ultima_data = $("#user_data tbody tr:first td:first").text().trim().split("-");
      var ultimo_dia = +ultima_data[0];
      var ultimo_mes = +ultima_data[1];
      var ultimo_ano = +ultima_data[2];
      this.date.setDate(ultimo_dia);
      this.date.setMonth(ultimo_mes-1);
      this.date.setYear(ultimo_ano);
      this.date.setDate( this.date.getDate()+1);
   }else{
      this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth()+1);
      this.date.setDate(1);
   }
   return  novaData(this.date);
}
}

  var DateIndexer = new CellDate(new Date(Date.now()));

$('#add').click(function(){

   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1">'+DateIndexer.getNextDate()+'</td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html);
  });
```

Within the class in `getNextDate`, when it is true (the table already has rows), creating a new row fills the date field with the date of the next day of the last row already entered.

But if the table has no row inserted, it returns in the date field `NaN-NaN-NaN`, because it does not enter into the `else`.

If you put `console.log(DateIndexer.getNextDate());` before the function `$('#add').click(function(){` returns `01-08-2019`.

But if put `console.log(DateIndexer.getNextDate());` inside the function `$('#add').click(function(){` returns `NaN-NaN-NaN`.

Table `#user_data`:

```
<div class="container box">
   <h3 align="center">MAPA DE TRABALHO</h3>
   <h5 align="center">Ajudante de Ação Direta - Turno: Manhã</h5>
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
   <br />
    <div align="right">
     <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-info"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div id="alert_message"></div>
    <table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Data</th>
       <th>Resp. de Turno</th>
       <th>Apoio</th>
       <th>Elementos ALA A</th>
       <th>Elementos ALA B</th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you put a `console.log` inside the `else` to verify? Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @takendarkk Not necessary.  `0` is a falsy value.

Comment: @nick zoum Yes. No error is returned in the console.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without the HTML. Show us the `user_data` table.

Comment: @Amy I already added the table `#user_data`

Comment: Always try to avoid stuff like  if($('#user_data tbody tr').length). make it  if($('#user_data tbody tr').length > 0) for beeing sure

Comment: @SandroSchaurer As I already noted in an earlier comment, that is not necessary.  Zero is a falsey value.

Comment: Make sure that you are using jQuery and not the `$` function supplied by most modern browsers

Comment: I've copied your code to a blank page and imported jquery. It works fine.

Comment: @nick zoum I'm using this jquery `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html has no `tbody`, returning null on you first execution

Try to include a tbody

```
<table id="user_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>Data</th>
      <th>Resp. de Turno</th>
      <th>Apoio</th>
      <th>Elementos ALA A</th>
      <th>Elementos ALA B</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This will fix your code here:

```
$('#add').click(function(){

   var html = '<tr>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data1">'+DateIndexer.getNextDate()+'</td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data2"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data3"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data4"></td>';
   html += '<td contenteditable id="data5"></td>';
   html += '<td><button type="button" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button></td>';
   html += '</tr>';
   $('#user_data tbody').prepend(html); //<--- right here

});
```

Your condition on `if` need to be reviewed too, because on the first execution `tbody` was empty, change to this

```
class CellDate {
    constructor(start_date) {
        this.date = start_date;
    }
    getNextDate() {
   //here the change for if condition     
   if ($('#user_data tbody tr') != null && $('#user_data tbody tr').length > 0) {
            var ultima_data = $("#user_data tbody tr:first td:first").text().trim().split("-");
            var ultimo_dia = +ultima_data[0];
            var ultimo_mes = +ultima_data[1];
            var ultimo_ano = +ultima_data[2];
            this.date.setDate(ultimo_dia);
            this.date.setMonth(ultimo_mes - 1);
            this.date.setYear(ultimo_ano);
            this.date.setDate(this.date.getDate() + 1);
            console.log('if', this.date);
        } else {
            this.date.setMonth(this.date.getMonth() + 1);
            this.date.setDate(1);
            console.log('else', this.date);
        }
        return novaData(this.date);
    }
}
```

Code here https://jsfiddle.net/nzb0tdjq/

Comment: The problem persists, it only works if you already have a line inserted

Comment: when running with the code that I posted, when I call the `else` I get this message `if Invalid Date`

Comment: If you put it this way it [link](https://jsfiddle.net/t0h3uq6a/) works, 
But if you put it early in the JavaScript `fetch_data();` where the code looks like this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/t0h3uq6a/1/) does not work

Comment: @BrunoPinto I didn't found any `fetch_data` reference on your question :-|   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56871306/function-does-not-enter-the-else/56871725